# Looking for a way to search an html page with javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

what I would like to do is to the html page for a specific string and read in a certain amount of characters after it and present those characters in an anchor tag.

the problem I'm having is figuring out how to search the page for a string everything I've found relates to by tag or id. Also hoping to make it a greasemonkey script for my personal use.

```
function createlinks(srchstart,srchend){
    var page = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;

    page = page.substring(srchstart,srchend);

    if (page.search("file','http:") != -1)
    {
        var begin = page.search("file','http:") + 7;
        var end = begin + 79;

        var link = page.substring(begin,end);
        document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="'+link+'">LINK</a> | ';

        createlinks(end+1,page.length);
    }       
};
```

what I came up with unfortunately after finding the links it loops over the document again

Comment: What do you mean by "present those characters in an anchor tag"? Do you want to create a dynamic link to them of some sort?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?  Perhaps you want to get rid of the Java tag?

Comment: Before I tell how to do this in Java, can you confirm this isn't just about javascript?

Comment: sorry more javascript related and the issue I had wasn't with creating a the link but rather finding the string to use as the dynamic link I guess you could call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assisted Direction

---

1. Lookup JavaScript Regex.
2. Apply your regex to the page's HTML (see below).

Different regex functions do different things.  You could search the document for the string, as suggested, but you'd have to do it recursively, since the string you're searching for may be listed in multiple places.

#### To Get the Text in the Page

---

- JavaScript:  `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML`
- jQuery: `$('html').html()`

*Note*:

1. IE may require the element to be capitalized (eg 'HTML') - I forget
2. Also, the document may have newline characters `\n` that might want to take out, since one could be between the string you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in javascript you've got the whole document in the DOM tree.  You an search for your string by recursively searching the DOM for the string you want.  This is striaghtforward; I'll put in pseudocode because you want to think about what libraries (if any) you're using.

```
function search(node, string):
    if node.innerHTML contains string
       -- then you found it
    else
       for each child node child of node
           search(child,string)
       rof
    fi
```